# Laravel ajax model to show posts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a `foreach()` from database table, I want to show a popup/model to show its extra information.

I am showing just title and description and on click i want to open up a popup and show its extra information.

```
@foreach($myProjects as $project)
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 notes notes--blue">
        <a href="#edit-note" data-toggle="modal" style="background-color: #f9f9f9;border-bottom: 5px solid #42A5F5">
            <div class="notes__title">{{$project->title}}</div>
            <div class="notes__body">{{$project->description}}</div>
        </a>
        <div class="notes__actions" data-demo-action="delete-listing">
             <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="notes__actions1" data-demo-action="delete-listing">
              <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="notes__actions2" data-demo-action="delete-listing">
              <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I am completely blank, Should i fetch post id to a hidden html tag and on model button click an ajax call will fetch the record info based on the `id` ?

Comment: Yes, it's better via ajax (vuejs, angularjs, reactjs). Just anything ajax.

Comment: I think you dont have to make ajax, if you have already all extra information selected in first query. You can place informatin in hidden div and just display them after some action (click) in popup.
You dont have to make another and another queries to DB in ajax.

Comment: So an ajax call will take off getting the post id ?

Comment: @Autista_z I have array for posts. Please answer the question... :)

Comment: Yea, hidden block with id based on post ID and then, after click on button with e.g. data attribute ID select the content of this hidden block and showing it in modal. Its similar solution as guyfawkes-s, but without unnecessary queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a `data-id` attribute to one of the elements, possibly the wrapper, then add something like

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.clickable_element', function(e){
  if ($(this).data('id')) {
        $.ajax({
           url : 'your detail url', 
           data: { id: parseInt( $(this).data('id'), 10 ), 
           success : function(response){
               // open popup and add response into it.
           }
        })
  }
```

});

Update

I just noticed you already have bootstrap modal there.

you can add your data-id to `data-toggle` element then in javascript

```
$('[data-toggle=modal]').on('shown.bs.modal' , function(){
  // do your ajax stuff
  // add response in `.modal-body`
})
```

Comment: So it will get the id and will send it to the controller right ? And is it a best practice ?

Comment: If you want to use ajax and modal at the same time, I believe so. BS 3 has an option for `remote` data if you want to give a try. you basically add full url of content will be loaded as data attribute ( or in caller function ) and bootstrap takes care of it . `data-remote='..myurl....?id={{$project->id}}'` http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Comment: Cool. I am glad it helped. Don't forget to mark as resolved if it worked.